# Microsoft Visual Studio 'Unknown Bitmap Format' when editing the default toolbars

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I've created an application using Microsoft Foundation Class library (MFC) using the project creation wizard. I created a multiple-document interface (MDI) application. The wizard creates dummy toolbars and menus that you can work with. I extended the default toolbar with no issue however now when I try to edit it through the resource view, I get "Unknown Bitmap Format" and the toolbar doesn't open. I haven't changed the file outside of Visual Studio therefore I'm unsure as to what causing this. The toolbar still opens and works fine when the application is running, its just now I can't edit it. [The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOEFf.png)

I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. The only other similar post I can find is here http://www.databaseforum.info/2/8/1e1b848b13ed1254.html however no solution has been found for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same error, using bitmaps exported from GIMP - and I found this post (which I haven't still tried):

- https://www.curlybrace.com/words/2013/08/30/exporting-visual-studio-compatible-bitmaps-from-gimp/

> When exporting bitmaps from GIMP, two options must be selected in order for the bitmaps to be compatible with Visual Studio:
>
> 1. Under Compatibility Options, check “Do not write color space information”.
> 2. Under Advanced Options, select “R8 G8 B8” under 24 bits.

Comment: If you cannot access these options, try Image/Mode -> RGB