# Modify Toolbar for MFC MS Visual Studio 2019 app with Gimp

Tags: visual-studio, bitmap, mfc, visual-studio-2019, gimp

I'm trying to modify a toolbar's BMP file with GIMP 2.10.24 (tried with 2.9, too) for a MFC application in Visual Studio 2019's resource editor.

Using [these explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257697/microsoft-visual-studio-unknown-bitmap-format-when-editing-the-default-toolbar), I can save the BMP file so that it opens in Visual Studio.
I also set the mode to RGB and made sure there is no alpha channel.

The title of the MS VS editor reads

```
0x0, 1 bit, BMP
```

just like before.

The app builds OK, but when I run it,

```
VERIFY(toolBar->LoadToolBar(nID));
```

fails with an exception.

Is there anything else I need to do to make my toolbar load again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The BMP file format is surprisingly complex, and hardly anyone gets it right. Just to make sure that your bitmap is valid, open it up in MS Paint, and save it again. Though it seems strange that (apparently) you are using a monochrome (1bpp) bitmap.

Comment: You are right, its surprising to see '1 bit' ... especially as I see colors in Gimp, Visual Studio and also Paint! Saving it back from Paint makes it work in monochrome mode (but I loose the colors). Saving as 16 colors adds blank icons between the tools. Saving as 256 works, but screws up the colors (they show OK in paint and Studio). Saving as 24 bit makes it crash again. Weird. 
MS VS documentation talks about exporting and importing bitmaps for toolbars, but I only have 'Export', not 'Import' in my VS 2019. :-(
( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/toolbar-editor?view=msvc-160 )

Comment: Ok, so one piece of the puzzle is solved: GIMP cannot write conforming BMP files. Not much of a surprise there, considering that Adobe Photoshop won't, either. Regardless, if the image is recognized as a monochrome image, but you are seeing colors, you cannot be looking at a BMP file. It's probably an ICO, consisting of a monochrome mask and color information. Can you provide a hex dump of the image data in your question?

Comment: I remember having to downgrade GIMP to version 2.6.0 due to newer generating bitmaps which were unassimilable my MFC. You can get it on http://www.oldversion.com/windows/the-gimp-2-6-0

Comment: Go back to basics - use the resource editor to create your toolbar resource in the first place. Then, close the solution and compare the characteristics of the image file in the res folder with your own image file and see how they differ.

Also, consider showing screenshots of your image in the IDE and the properties, And maybe the snippet of the appropriate image data from the RC file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked out a solution that works with recent versions of GIMP (thanks to everyone who contributed!):

- Do NOT convert to RGB! The confusion comes from the fact that ‘Advanced options’ is only active if you convert to RGB, but you do not need the advanced options. Maybe that changed at one point in MSVS or in GIMP, because explanations on different forums are confusing about this point...
- Image/Mode -> Indexed colors (DO NOT CHANGE THIS)

File/Export as ... :

- Run-Length encoded : do not check
- Compatibility options : do not write color space information : check
- Advanced options : is not accessible, but that DOESN'T MATTER !
  Additional trick: you can copy-paste the buttons of toolbars (not the entire toolbar) one by one from Gimp to VS (if the color settings in Gimp are as explained above ; if not, you loose / mix up the colors).

Tested with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 enterprise edition and GIMP 2.10.